# Query string sending value = 0, not new assigned value in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, initialization, jquery-events

**In Js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var trxID=0;
var oHoldTable=$('#posHold').dataTable();
$('#posHold tbody tr').die();
$('#posHold tbody tr').live('dblclick', function () {
    var oHData = oHoldTable.fnGetData( this );
    trxID=oHData[0];
    if (oHData[0] > 0) {
        $.post("VoidTransaction",{
            trxID:oHData[0]
        },function(data){
            if (data.rst==1) {
                parent.tb_remove();
                $('.btnPrint').trigger('click');
            }
        });
    }else{
        alert("No Transaction is Available for Void");
    }
});

$(".btnPrint").printPage({
 url: "receipts/void.jsp?trxID="+trxID,
    attr: "href",
    message:"Your document is being created"
})
});
```

I have declared a variable trxID and initialized with 0. Then assign a value in .live even handler such as:

```
 trxID=oHData[0];
```

but query string still sending value = 0, not new assigned value.

```
url: "receipts/void.jsp?trxID="+trxID
```

how get updated value of trxID?

Comment: Are you sure `oHData` is a populated array and `oHoldTable.fnGetData( this )` is returning the correct values? Try `console.log`ing those.

Comment: Fyi, `.live()` and `.die()` are deprecated in favour of `.on()`/`.off()` or `.delegate()` (pre-1.7)

Comment: yes OHData return the value of zero index i.e 56 last time when I place alert(oHData[0]); @FabrícioMatté

Comment: $('.btnPrint').trigger('click'); should be $('.btnPrint').trigger('printpage');

Answer (score 0):

I have made a little change, hope it will work fine and I think no need to explain. You can guess easily!

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var trxID=0;

var oHoldTable=$('#posHold').dataTable();
$('#posHold tbody tr').off();
$('#posHold tbody tr').on('dblclick', function () {
    var oHData = oHoldTable.fnGetData( this );
    trxID=oHData[0];
    if (oHData[0] > 0) {
        $.post("VoidTransaction",{
            trxID:oHData[0]
        },function(data){
            if (data.rst==1) {
                parent.tb_remove();
                $('.btnPrint').trigger('click');
            }
        });
    }else{
        alert("No Transaction is Available for Void");
    }

    $(".btnPrint").printPage({

        url: "receipts/void.jsp?trxID="+trxID,
        attr: "href",
        message:"Your document is being created"
    })

});



});
```